# Prove that any relation that is a partial order / equivalence is identity relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

Prove that any relation that is both an equivalence relation and a partial ordering is the identity relation.  That is, if X is a set and R is a relation on X that is both a partial ordering and an equivalence relation, then aRb if and only if a=b.

Is this logic sound?

By definition of transitivity, if (a,b) exists and (b,c) exists, then (a,c) exists. However we know this is also symmetric which means (c,a) exists. By definition of antisymmetry, if those two ordered pairs exist, then a = c.

Also by reflexivity, (a,a) exists for all a, and in these ordered pairs, b = a.

Comment: Think about that all equivalelence relations  in X make a partition of X.
The thinest partition you can make is element by element.

And you have a partial order since you can set a=b, a pair of elements that are equal.

Comment: Your use of the transitive law is garbled. In fact, you don't need transitivity. Any relation which is symmetric, reflexive, and antisymmetric is the identity relation, which is basically what you've shown.